Is it possible to pivot table in mysql based on columns only with variable columns name without extention
I mean, given input
NAME location
ANNA USA
Alica USA
Lisa CA
Arch CA
Ketty Germany
...

I want result
USA   CA    Germany ...
Anna  Lisa  Ketty ...
Alica Arch  

Is it possible to make it with Mysql without extensions and vars?

welcome to our DBA place! the question has already an answer however, for the next time can you make it easier and add the create table statements, the insert statements, so that we are all working on the same base and it is easier just to use your code? I think there is a link for that, just I could not find it now.

Since MySQL does not have a built-in pivot function you have to dynamically construct the SQL query .
Using
WITH pivotLocations AS (
    SELECT name,
           location,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY name) AS rowNum
    FROM myTable
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN location = 'USA' THEN name END) AS 'USA',
       MAX(CASE WHEN location = 'CA' THEN name END) AS 'CA',
       MAX(CASE WHEN location = 'Germany' THEN name END) AS 'Germany'
FROM pivotLocations
GROUP BY rowNum;

We get the result
USA      CA     Germany
Alica   Arch    Ketty
ANNA    Lisa    null

ROW_NUMBER() assigns a unique row number to each name within the same location and we need that that MAX does not return only one result per location.

Now we need to dynamically construct the SQL.
SET @locations = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
    'MAX(CASE WHEN location = ''', location, ''' THEN name END) AS `', location, '`'
)) INTO @locations
FROM myTable;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'WITH pivotLocations AS (',
    '   SELECT name, location, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location ORDER BY name) AS row_num ',
    '   FROM myTable ',
    ') ',
    'SELECT ', @locations, ' ',
    'FROM pivotLocations ',
    'GROUP BY row_num;'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

Note GROUP_CONCAT has a limit of 1024 characters, increase if needed.
See example
